# multithreaded crawler with different proxy for each thread, the right way?

Tags: python, urllib2, web-crawler, httplib2

I'm going to write a multithreaded crawler that is planned to run on about 10M pages, in order to speed thing up I need to fetch about 10~ different pages simultaneity.

Each of the crawler-threads will use a different proxy and push the results to a queue, on the other side I'll have a few more workers that will fetch the results from the queue, parse and insert them to a DB.

Is that the right approach? will I have problems saving too many results in the queue? should I be worried about locks? (using the queue module).
Which HTTP library will be the best for my needs? (httplib2/urllib2).

when creating each thread, should I pass new instances of the request object to each thread or should I move the request object and use its "getPage" function in the thread?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) library ([documantation part for proxies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies))

Answer (score 0):

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)'s the way to go.

Here's a page describing how to set up the proxy middleware to use multiple proxies: http://mahmoud.abdel-fattah.net/2012/04/16/using-scrapy-with-different-many-proxies/